# Symfony2 - Two database connections in one bundle - can't seem to set it up - see my code

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

This is what I am trying to do:

```
namespace BundleTwo\Controller;

use BundleOne\Entity\TestEntity;

class TestController
{

    public function pageAction()
    {

        $insert = new TestEntity();
        $insert->fieldName('test');
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager('dbcon2');   
        $em->persist($insert);
        $em->flush();

    }

}
```

…so the code above is in Bundle 2 which uses an Entity from Bundle 1 - but it needs to use DB connection2.

I can  use this http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html to set up the two DB connections and I can see how you can define which EM is used by a bundle, but I want 2 connections for one bundle.

I think the above code would work, but when I run  app/console doctrine:schema:update --em=dbcon2  it doesn't populate anything in the DB and doesn't detect any Entities. I think I need to somehow get it to realise that BundleOne\Entity\TestEntity is also used by Bundle 2 and DB 2.

If I could put settings inside BundleTwo that set the DB connection used for BundleOne\Entity\TestEntity then that might do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify which bundles contains entity metadata with `mapping` property

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        default_entity_manager:   dbcon1
        entity_managers:
            dbcon1:
                connection: dbcon1
                mappings:
                    BundleOne: ~
            dbcon2:
                connection: dbcon2
                mappings:
                    BundleOne: ~
```

Answer (score 0):

As you surmised, you must tell each entity manager which bundles to use when looking for entities.

Something like:

```
orm:
    default_entity_manager:       default
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
   #auto_mapping: true

    entity_managers:

        default:
            connection: default
            mappings:

        games:
           connection: games
           mappings:
                CeradGameBundle: ~

        accounts:
           connection: accounts
           mappings:
                FOSUserBundle: ~
                CeradAccountBundle: ~
```

So your dbcon2 would have bundle 1 and bundle 2 listed.  If this answer does not help then please update your question and show your doctrine orm config.